# Proper design to reuse the results of more general functions

Tags: python, performance, oop, python-2.7

Let's say we have a situation when we create a class which has some set of parameters and we can pull some data for an instance of that class (say, for some particular date) from a database (which is supposedly not too fast). This is what we have:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

    def getData(self, date):
        return # here goes the query result converted to dict
```

Now, what if I'd like to have a couple of functions in that class which gets some particular frequently used things from that database:

```
    def getT(self, date):
        return self.getData(date)['temperature']

    def getP(self, date):
        return self.getData(date)['pressure']
```

The problem here is if I'd like to query for temperature and then pressure, it has to run the query twice. How can I avoid this? Is the design I suggest wrong?

Comment: If you are using python 3.2, you can use `functools.lru_cache`.

Comment: @HYRY Edited tags: I'm using python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache the results of the query by date in the object instances. Something like this:

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self._datacache = {}

    def getData(self, date):
        if date not in self._datacache:
            self._datacache[date] = # here goes the query result converted to dict
        return self._datacache[date]
```

There are variations possible, but that's the basic idea. With this version, your other getters can work as you have them written. Or you can just work directly with the query results.

Comment: Beat me to it. Though I would add caching into getData, that way the caching would be transparent to the other functions.